# How should we handle the paid version of Desktop Dungeons?

Tags: discussion, tags

With the paid version of Desktop Dungeons now in beta, it is time to figure out how we are going to handle it.  Specifically, while the game has many similarities to the free version, there are a number of changes to how things work.  The creators have said that they have no plans to circle back and apply these balance changes to the free version of the game.  This means that many of our existing questions, especially the ones dealing with strategies, really only apply to the free version.

Should we create a new tag for the paid version of the game?  Should we create a new tag for the free version, and transition all existing questions to it?  How should we handle questions that would apply equally to both versions?

I'm particularly worried that it won't be clear to new users which version we're talking about.  So I think we'll likely need to both rename the existing tag, and create a tag with a new name, so that either one by itself is clear (and maybe keep the current tag for things that apply to both versions)?

Comment: The good news is there are only 15 questions right now, so handling them manually isn't too bad.

Answer (score 7):

**Add [desktop-dungeons-free](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons-free) and [desktop-dungeons-paid](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons-paid) tags, migrate all existing questions to [desktop-dungeons-free](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons-free), and delete [desktop-dungeons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons).**

It's not entirely accurate but it is very clear what each is about, and both have the same prefix for auto-completion. I also thought about [desktop-dungeons-free](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons-free) and [desktop-dungeons-unity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons-unity), but I have not seen unity as an *official* version name, so we should probably avoid that.

As for questions that ask about a feature shared between the two games, then they can either receive any one of these tags, or both of them. The advantage of not creating a new tag is that the feature in question may later change for one of the versions but not the other, so it would no longer be shared and should get only one of the tags anyway.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards also.  Of the current 15 questions, I think about 10 only apply to the free version.  The other 5 could have both tags.

Comment: Given that there seem to be significant differences at this point between the paid (beta) and free versions, I think it makes sense to tag them separately and use both tags for questions that apply to both ... if the versions converge in the future, we can always create a synonym for the tags, and if they continue to diverge, it'll be easier to separate the questions when we have 15 than when we have 50.

Comment: I've exchanged all instances of [tag:desktop-dungeons] with [tag:desktop-dungeons-free].

Comment: Are you sure we want to have both tags for questions that apply to both versions? That's not how we've been rolling so far.

Comment: I agree with @badp, is it not possible to just have a [desktop-dungeons](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons) tag which is relevant to both the free and paid versions.

Answer (score 2):

I know that Oak's answer has already been implemented, but I wanted to add an alternative suggestion because I don't feel that the [desktop-dungeons-paid](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons-paid) tag fits very well (and there isn't an accepted answer yet).

I would like to propose the following solution:

- Questions that are relevant to the full Desktop Dungeons game should be tagged [desktop-dungeons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons) (this would include questions that are relevant to both the free version and the full version)
- Questions that are related only to the free Desktop Dungeons game should be tagged [desktop-dungeons-free](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons-free)

The rationale behind this being that most users coming to the site will ask questions about the full version (especially when it comes out of beta) and should not have to distinguish between selecting between the *paid* or *free* tags; they will just be able to select the *desktop-dungeons* tag.

Answer (score -1):

We can create two tags: "desktop-dungeons-alpha" and "desktop-dungeons-beta"

Comment: Or "desktop-dungeons-free" and "desktop-dungeons-paid"?

Comment: Yah, beta isn't a good idea, since it won't be in beta for long.